# How dose blender handle tiny roughness in BSDF with GGX?

Tags: shaders, source-code, roughness

I am curioused about the implementation of principled BSDF in blender. As we know, the GGX would produce "inf" value when the roughness is close to zero. Some renders, such as [filament](https://google.github.io/filament/Filament.html#materialsystem/parameterization/remapping), remap roughness to [0.085, 1] to prevent the problem. According to the [source code of principled BSDF in blender](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_principled_bsdf.osl#L103), it seems that blender would use a different GGX implementation `microfacet_ggx_aniso_fresnel` when roughness is smaller than 0.075. However, I cannot further find the implementation about `microfacet_ggx_aniso_fresnel`.

So, what would be done when roughness is close to zero?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more about development of Blender in C than about it's functionality.

Comment: You seem to be looking for the OSL closure located in `\blender\intern\cycles\kernel\osl\closures_setup.h`. The publication "Physically-based shading at disney" by Brent Burley may be of interest.